# SQL Server Force Encryption with a DoD Certificate

Tags: sql-server, security, server

I have a SQL Server 2012 Standard hosted on a WIN 2008 R2 DataCenter 64 bit.  I have a requirement to set the Force Encryption on the SQL Server to Yes, which is easy to do.

What I am needing help with is for the DoD Certificate requirement, where do I get the DoD Certificate from? and Do I just install it on the server where SQL Server resides?
I found this link , I wonder if I can use this:
http://dodpki.c3pki.chamb.disa.mil/rootca.html

Comment: is you want to Encryption SP and View ??

Comment: Can you give more details please.  Are you asking if i want to encrypt connection for the stored procedures and sql Views?

Answer (score 0):

Your hyperlink is not publicly available, however, since the name on the file is rootca.html it may contain information about how to get a root CA Certificate provisioned. When you use SQL Server Configuration Manager to set force encryption to true, you must either configure a certificate to use or the server will used a self signed certificate. The security concern with only setting this option and using a self signed certificate is that it leaves your server vulnerable to a man in the middle attack. The requirements for creating the certificate to be used for encrypting connections are on MSDN. I would recommend at least using a domain certificate generated by the domain certificate authority. You probably need to adhere to standards if this is for the DOD. Once the certificate and related private key are generated, they need to be added to the certificate store of the service account running the SQL Server database engine. After that, it can be selected for use in the configuration manager in the same dialog box as the force encryption option under a different tab. Once this is configured and the service is restarted, you can verify that the connections are encrypted by using the sql statement below:

```
    select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```